# Ajax minify specify output directory VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I am trying to integrate Ajax minify in the build of VS 2010. We are using the syntax as shown below and it does work but I want the file to copied to a specific folder. Currently its creating the file in the root directory. How can i change this.

This is the syntax I am using

```
<AjaxMin Switches="-global:jQuery,$"
  JsSourceFiles="@(JS)"  JsCombinedFileName="xx.min.js"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use

```
<AjaxMin Switches="-global:jQuery,$"
 JsSourceFiles="@(JS)"  JsCombinedFileName="Scripts\xx.min.js"/>
```